# How get the full name of the country in the bootstrap select country picker control

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm using the bootstrap select country picker by https://mojoaxel.github.io/bootstrap-select-country/index.html. When I do $(this).val() it's giving me country short codes instead of the full country name.

How can I get the full country name or I have to use a delimited text file like http://www.iso.org/iso/list-en1-semic-3.txt and map the country short codes to the fullnames?

Comment: have you read the documentation on usage ? the examples are not using the val attribute, try following the examples

Comment: Yes I have and this $("#Country").val($(this).val()); will assign a shortcode to the country attribute. I'm not seeing an example for full name, point me to the right direction please.